# boost::is_member_function_pointer_of?

Tags: c++, templates, boost

Boost has is_member_function_pointer, but not is_member_function_pointer_of, which would determine whether the type is a member function pointer of another class. So, for instance,

```
boost::is_member_function_pointer_of<void(ClassA::*)(), ClassA>::value == true
boost::is_member_function_pointer_of<void(ClassA::*)(), ClassB>::value == false
```

Is this possible to write?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pointers to member function types are just pointer to member types that happen to be built from a function type.

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, class C>
struct is_member_function_pointer_of
    : public std::false_type
{};

template <typename FT, class C>
struct is_member_function_pointer_of<FT C::*, C>
    : public std::is_function<FT>::type
{};
```

Boost versions could be substituted where C++11 is not supported.

Note that this ignores the implicit conversion from `T Base::*` to `T Derived::*`.

Comment: "Pointers to member function types are just pointer to member types that happen to be built from a function type." OK I never knew that. Thanks.

Comment: I can't get this to work (Sorry I just can't figure out how to format this :( )    struct a {void func(){}}; struct b{}; template<class fnc, class c> bool test(fnc f, c* pC) { return is_member_function_pointer_of<fnc, c>::value; } bool b1 = test(&a::func, new a); //false bool b2 = test(&a::func, new b); //false

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned I was using boost, could you try that?

Comment: `template <typename T, class C>  
struct is_member_function_pointer_of  
   : public boost::false_type  
{};  
  
template <typename FT, class C>  
struct is_member_function_pointer_of<FT C::*, C>  
   : public boost::is_function<FT>::type  
{};  
  
  
struct a {void func(){}};  
struct b{};  
  
template<class fnc, class c>  
bool test(fnc f, c* pC)  
{
   return is_member_function_pointer_of<fnc, c>::value;  
}  
  
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])  
{  
   bool b1 = test(&a::func, new a);  
   bool b2 = test(&a::func, new b);  
   return 0;  
}  `

Comment: I still get `b1` true with that version (assuming I add code to print its value).

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=72f2161dc363920ba4e63f99c7bfdde3-34d68efd8b103c4390d111926401aa17

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't work in msvc2008. I'll keep this in mind whenever I upgrade my compiler. I guess thats why its best to use boost/std for this kind of thing instead of trying to roll your own.